# Event to detect orientation (landscape and portrait mode) for "samsung galaxy Android 2.3.5"

Tags: jquery, android, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

**I want to show different page design for landscape and portrait mode.**

**I want an event which fire every time when user change the mobile from "landscape to portrait" and "portrait to landscape" and page show different design for both the mode.**

Also in my code each time show the landscape design it is not able to detect the portrait mode.Even when I am running the page in portrait mode.

For following mobile device:

**Device**: Samsung Galaxy ,

**Os version:** Android 2.3.5.

In this I am using:

**Jquery mobile version:** 1.1.0. ,

**Jquery version:** 1.7.1

My code is running well for **"iphone,ipad and htc android mobile"** but when I am test this in "Samsung Galaxy" then it is showing landscape page design for both the landscape and portrait mode.

**My code is:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pagecontent.ui-content").css({ 'padding': '0px', 'margin': '0px' });
    checkClientTimeZone();

    position = $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation();
    pagecontentChanges();

    //        $(window).bind("orientationchange", pagecontentChanges);

});
$.event.special.orientationchange.orientation = get_orientation = function () {
    var elem = document.documentElement;
    //alert(elem && elem.clientWidth / elem.clientHeight < 1.1 ? "portrait" :       "landscape");
    return elem && elem.clientWidth / elem.clientHeight < 1.1 ? "portrait" : "landscape";
};
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        position = $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation();
        pagecontentChanges();
    }, 500);
}, false);
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        position = $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation();
        pagecontentChanges();
    }, 500);
}, false);


function pagecontentChanges() {

    if (position == "portrait") {
        $("#headertext").css({ "text-align": "center", "margin-top": "-2.6em" });
        $("#login_content").removeClass("landscap_logincontent");
        $("#registerdiv").removeClass("landscap_divwhite");
        $("#tylenol").css({ "width": "100%", "float": "", "margin-right": "0px" });
        $("#button_div .ui-btn").css(" margin-top", ".5em");
        $("#loginbluelink").css("text-align", "center");
        $("#redromantext").css("text-align", "center");
        $('#registerdiv').css({ "float": "" });
        $("#registertext").css({ "margin-top": "0px" });
        $(".divwhite").css({ "width": "60%" });

        $("#loginheader").attr("src", "@img_css_scpt/test_mobile/images/logon_header.png");

    }
    if (position == "landscape") {
        $("#headertext").css({ "text-align": "left", "padding-left": "5%", "margin-top": "1em" });
        $("#login_content").addClass("landscap_logincontent");
        $("#registerdiv").addClass("landscap_divwhite");
        $("#tylenol").css({ "width": "55%", "float": "left", "margin-right": ".5em" });
        $("#button_div .ui-btn").css(" margin-top", "0px");
        $("#loginbluelink").css("text-align", "left");
        $("#redromantext").css("text-align", "left");
        $("#registertext").css({ "margin-top": "5px" });
        $(".divwhite").css({ "width": "71%" });

        $("#loginheader").attr("src", "@img_css_scpt/test_mobile/images/landscap_header_logon.png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `window.resize` event handler a `setTimeout`:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        position = $.event.special.orientationchange.orientation();
        pagecontentChanges();
    }, 500);
});
```

That's what I did for my own `window.resize` event handlers for my Droid X that runs Android 2.3.4.

Comment: I have try this But it is not working and always show the landscap design.

Comment: @user1045389 I just noticed that you are binding to the `window.resize` event twice. Why?

Comment: I have added two resize one for desktop pc and another for listner for mobile.

Comment: Hello I have change the code by the above which I have edited but not working for android